# Variables in HTML heredoc

Tags: php

I have a function here which basically exits without ruining the layout:

```
function bomb($str,$wrap) {
    $error = $str;
    echo $wrap;
    include_once '../include/foot.php';
    exit();
}
```

And then I declared a long HTML [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#PHP):

```
$signup=
<<<HTML
   blah Blah blah
   <span>$error</span>
   blah blah blah
HTML;
```

Underneath I have some form validations in which if it's invalid, I'd throw the function:

`bomb("Invalid field",$signup);`

But it seems that the `$error` wasn't called during the `echo $wrap` in the bomb function - it returns nothing.
I doubt that I have to globalize the `$error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get what you're trying to do.  However, the content of *$signup* is already stored, and you can't "pass in" *$error* to *$wrap* as you would otherwise pass in a variable as a parameter inside a function.

Try this:

```
function bomb($str) {

     echo msg($str);

     include_once '../include/foot.php';    

     exit();

}



function msg($error) {

    $signup = <<<HTML
       blah Blah blah
       <span>$error</span>
       blah blah blah
HTML;

    return $signup;

}
```

I think that should work.  The change is that it instead uses a function, which **does** accept a parameter, and return a string (the heredoc) based on whatever variable you pass in to that parameter.  Give it a shot.

Comment: So It's just impossible? Is there any way around this?

Comment: I also tried using `$str` in the heredoc instead of the `$error` but that just doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot when I'm home. :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked but I want another variable in the bomb function in which I can choose which function to execute to.